# Could not send Message, Broken pipe, Error writing to XMLStreamWriter, No open start element, when trying to write end element

Tags: java, soap, timeout, cxf, response

I have two applications ARMS and ODOC, 
ARMS (Server) has exposed synchronous soap web services and ODOC (Client) is consuming synchronous soap web services.
ODOC is sending request to ARMS and after few minutes (say 3 to 5 minutes) it is getting timeout.
It is likely that the ODOC could not receive response and ARMS could not send response since the connection has broken.

> Questions:

1. Which application has to set timeout ? and How?
2. What is the maximum limit of timeout ?
3. What is the default timeout value?
4. Is there any why after timeout, ODOC could receive response and ARMS
   could send response.

*Below is the stacktrace at ARMS end while sending response back to ODOC.*

```
Interceptor for {http://org.planet.ARMSinterfaceservice/}ARMSService#{http://org.planet.webservices.ARMSinterfaceservice/}migrateRMPlan has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.writeInternal(NIOSocketMuxer.java:1070)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.write(NIOSocketMuxer.java:989)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:622)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:587)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:472)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.flush(CharsetChunkOutput.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.flush(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:193)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.flush(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:741)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 30 more
2018-05-25 08:38:34,041 WARN  LogUtils:449 - Interceptor for {http://org.planet.webservices.ARMSinterfaceservice/}ARMSService#{http://org.planet.webservices.ARMSinterfaceservice/}migrateRMPlan has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error writing to XMLStreamWriter.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:312)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.wrapExceptionAsFault(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No open start element, when trying to write end element
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1522)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1551)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:648)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeEndElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:299)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Which application has to set timeout ? and How?

   > Generally its client side, but connections can be terminated by server side, gateway/firewall(generally defaults 20min) after idle timeout/ receive timeout. CXF client side configuration parameters is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) and server side configuration parameters is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/server-http-transport.html#ServerHTTPTransport-Theserverelement)
2. What is the maximum limit of timeout ?
3. What is the default timeout value?

   > Please check the default timeout [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html)
4. Is there any why after timeout, ODOC could receive response and ARMS could send response.

   > No, but you can use async clients but again in this case you need to have combination of timeouts(solution is just NIO, it will not solve the actual problem).
   >
   > Ideal solution would be to use JMS/messaging with a broker and make your application async. You can configure both your cxf client and server by adding jms transport, please refer [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/soap-over-jms-10-support.html) to enable jms transport.You can have both SOAP over JMS and SOAP over HTTP working in tandem.